# Angular unable to start

Tags: angular, angular-cli

[image]

This is my first attempt on learning Angular JS and trying to run an application from [here](https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-GettingStarted/tree/master/APM-Start).

Below is the `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "apm",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
      "ng": "ng",
      "start": "ng serve -o",
      "build": "ng build",
      "test": "ng test",
      "lint": "ng lint --type-check",
      "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
      "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
      "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
      "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
      "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
      "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
      "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
      "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
      "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
      "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
      "core-js": "^2.4.1",
      "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
      "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@angular/cli": "1.6.3",
      "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
      "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
      "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
      "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
      "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
      "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
      "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
      "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
      "karma": "~1.7.0",
      "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
      "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
      "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
      "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
      "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
      "protractor": "~5.1.2",
      "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
      "tslint": "~5.3.2",
      "typescript": "~2.3.3"
    }
  }
```

I've executed the command `npm install` to make sure all dependancies have been up to date but when I try `npm start` the above screenshot is what I'm hitting.

I've just installed `Angular CLI` and verified using `ng --version` which showing me `1.6.3` so I assume CLI been installed correctly. What could've be the problem?

Comment: Why do you start learning with a version of angular that is already several months old (4.0.0)? Read the official getting started: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Comment: I'm actually following the course that subscribed from Pluralsight..thinking to start from somewhere, anywhere. Anyway, thanks for the heads up, will definitely take a look at your link

Comment: @IsaacLem  "@angular/cli": "1.6.3", supports angular 5 only ... you need to create a new project using `ng new` which creates the package.json with angular 5 dependency and does the npm install. for you or you can skip the automatic install

Comment: Originally it was "@angular/cli": "1.2.4" at `package.json` and I thought that my CLI version is 1.6.3 and hence I've updated the value myself. I tried to revert back to 1.2.4 and re-run `npm install` and `npm start` its still hitting same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have cloned the project and it works fine.
You have to use `ng server` instead of `npm start`.

You could also update the local cli with this commands

```
npm uninstall @angular/cli
npm install @angular/cli@latest
```

UPDATE

I found an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4736) on angulars github repository with the same error message as yours.

The error is reproducible by deleting the configuration file for the `angular cli` called `.angular-cli.json`. I deleted it and got the same error message as you.

Check that this file is not missing in your project. If it's not there then restore it from git.

Comment: I was managed to execute the first command only. Second command throwing me `Invalid package name "@angular/cli/": name can only contain URL-friendly characters`

Comment: sorry there was a typo in that command, remove the / before @latest

Comment: both command been executed successfully and cli is again version 1.6.3 however trying `ng server` still hitting same issue

Comment: @IsaacLem He meant `ng serve`.

Comment: @zgue: Big thumbs up! Thanks for the update. It is indeed the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

Just upgrade Angular CLI and run ng new  on new folder.
 There is only small changes between Angular 4 and Angular 5.